# Set the spacing between title and v7 drawer toggle

Tags: android, android-support-library, drawertoggle

I'm now using ActionBarDrawerToggle of the v7 support library. But the drawer icon is directly at the title font as I have disabled showHomeEnabled. How can I set more free space between the title and the toggle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this is sadly not really realizable.

The simplest thing to do is to use ActionBarCompat or if you're just caring about that on 5.0+, Theme.Material. It looks much better then and obviously, Google kinda wants us to use ActionBarCompat as there are some issues with ActionBarDrawerToggle on 4.3- !

Hope I could still help some people