# Padding between action bar start and DrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using support v7's new ActionBarDrawerToggle, but the toggle is directly at the action bar. How can I set a padding to it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the spacing between title and v7 drawer toggle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561238/set-the-spacing-between-title-and-v7-drawer-toggle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AppCompat is the simplest solution to this.